# Missing setSupportBackgroundTintList method for AppCompatCheckBox

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Based on [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) we now have the ability to tint the widgets on older devices as well. Unfortunately `setSupportBackgroundTintList()` is missing for [AppCompatCheckBox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatCheckBox.html).

Is there something that I've missed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I used that method successfully for [AppCompatSpinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.html) and obviously `AppCompatActivity` is extended in the Activity.

Comment: Where is your code? Where is your error?

Comment: AppCompatSpinner simply has no setSupportBackgroundTintList() method that I could access. I simply declare the widget in xml, reference it in code, and everything is fine. But I would like to tint it, so it will look alike on each version.

Comment: Have you not tried it's `android:backgroundTint` XML equivalent?

Comment: As per lint warning, it is only used on lollipop and above, it won't help in my situation. I am wondering how it is possible to have a widget having this method but the other not. It is a bug in the support library?

Comment: I am not sure, I just pull that from the docs that you gave. Actually if you look at the link you posted, `setSupportBackgroundTintList` is not even in there. I could only find it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html).

Comment: Yes, it seems like the `AppCompatCheckBox` is not a subclass of `TintableBackgroundView` . Therefore the things that I would like to achieve is not possible with this approach. Will try to find another way and get back with results.

Comment: In all honesty, the appcompat library is not perfect but at least you get most of the material design in pre-5.0 devices. I really would not worry too much about it as people using JellyBean and KitKat are not expecting Material Design or at least to have all of the features in their apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AppCompatCheckBox has no possibility (as far as I know) to programmatically nor from xml to set background tint on pre Lollipop, I thought of searching for a theme property that might help out. [This](https://gist.github.com/seanKenkeremath/c945c39cdf92af138395) post helped me out. Thanks @SeanKenkeremath. I used "colorControlNormal" and my AppCompatCheckBox turned out to be like I wanted from the beginning.

Here's the code:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <!-- Unchecked checkbox color-->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    ...
</style>
```